# Exception while interacting with MongoDB using Java

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to connect to MongoDB 3.6 with Java. When I tried to interact with the database, I received the following exception

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. 
Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, 
type=REPLICA_SET_GHOST, roundTripTime=0.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}]. Cause: Timed out after 30000 
ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector.
```

Why am I getting this error? What does it mean and how to solve this ?

Comment: can you check if Mongo service is running on your local machine?
Are you able to access Mongo shell?

Comment: I think the state of the message is CONNECTED, so by my opinion this is not a connection issue. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Why is the DML operation not getting processed ? and why is this error thrown "Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. "